# How to connect to an active .jar app session via rdp

Tags: java, windows, rdp, windows-server-2019, remoteapp

For my minecraft server I have the minecraft-server.jar running on my server. I'd like to connect to the running app via rdp from my personal pc, how could I do it?

I tried the below configuration, but it does not work the intended way

```
full address:s:****
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
disableremoteappcapscheck:i:1
alternate shell:s:rdpinit.exe
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
remoteapplicationname:s:Minecraft Server
remoteapplicationprogram:s:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MCServer_Forge\forge-1.16.5-36.2.39.jar
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:about:blank
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
allow font smoothing:i:1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming related question proper for this site. Please clarify it.